# Android camera display is getting stretched

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

Hi I am having problem with my camera application, the display is stretched. But the pictures are coming out ok. only the display is stretched. here is necessary code,
the surface changed call back

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                               int width, int height) {
      initPreview(width, height);
      startPreview();
    }
```

Here is the init preview function,

```
private void initPreview(int width, int height) {
    if (camera != null && previewHolder.getSurface() != null) {
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(previewHolder);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("PreviewDemo-surfaceCallback",
                "Exception in setPreviewDisplay()", t);
            Toast.makeText(PictureDemo.this, t.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if (!cameraConfigured) {
            Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size=getOptimalPreviewSize(width, height);
            Camera.Size pictureSize=getSmallestPictureSize(parameters);

            if (size != null && pictureSize != null) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
                parameters.setPictureSize(pictureSize.width,
                    pictureSize.height);
                parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
                camera.setParameters(parameters);
                cameraConfigured=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

other two functions are given below.

```
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(int width, int height) {
    Camera.Size result=null;
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    for (Camera.Size size : p.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
        if (size.width<=width && size.height<=height) {
            if (result==null) {
                result=size;
            } else {
                int resultArea=result.width*result.height;
                int newArea=size.width*size.height;
                if (newArea>resultArea) {
                    result=size;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private Camera.Size getSmallestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
    Camera.Size result=null;
    for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
        if (result == null) {
            result=size;
        }
        else {
            int resultArea=result.width * result.height;
            int newArea=size.width * size.height;
            if (newArea < resultArea) {
                result=size;
            }
        }
    }
    return(result);
}
```

So, what do you think is the problem. Why the display is stretched?

Comment: check activity orientation is landscape mode